# Raster to Vector reduces Segmentation accuracy too much (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I try to convert a segmented Image to a Feature Collection I loose accuracy, the new polygons are much bigger than after the segmentation.

```
import ee
import json
import eeconvert
import geopandas as gpd
ee.Initialize()
from IPython.display import Image

neuburg_area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[11.135076548789584,48.761643884690855],
[11.137136485313022,48.68078409548941],
[11.25901606294974,48.6821441576126],
[11.254896189902865,48.76571740675962],
[11.135076548789584,48.761643884690855]])
neuburg = neuburg_area.toGeoJSON()

img_col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
geometry = neuburg
img_col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
image = ee.Image(img_col.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-07-01').sort('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT').first())
image = image.clip(geometry)

seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(10) #36
snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC(image= image, 
  size= 32,  #32
  compactness= 5,    #5
  connectivity= 8,    #8
  neighborhoodSize=2,   #2
  seeds= seeds
).select(["B2_mean","B3_mean","B4_mean","B8_mean", 'clusters'], ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'clusters']) #32 size
clusters = snic.select('clusters')
clustervis = clusters.randomVisualizer()
Image(url=clustervis.getThumbUrl({"region":geometry,"bands":["viz-red","viz-green","viz-blue"]}))
```

That's how the later polygons should look like (Image after Segmentation):
[image: Image after Segmentation]

```
# Image to Feature Collection with single polygons
col = clusters.reduceToVectors()
Image(url=col.reduceToImage(["label"],"first").randomVisualizer().getThumbUrl({"region":geometry,"bands":["viz-red","viz-green","viz-blue"]}))
```

And that's how they look like:
[image: After RasterToVector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding snic.reproject to the first part of the code solves the problem:

```
seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(18) #36
snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC(image= image, 
  size= 32,  #32
  compactness= 5,    #5
  connectivity= 8,    #8
  neighborhoodSize=15,   #2
  seeds= seeds
).select(["B2_mean","B3_mean","B4_mean","B8_mean", 'clusters'], ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'clusters']) #32 size
snic = snic.reproject(crs = snic.projection(), scale = 10)
clusters = snic.select('clusters')
clustervis = clusters.randomVisualizer()
Image(url=clustervis.getThumbUrl({"region":geometry,"bands":["viz-red","viz-green","viz-blue"]}))
```